# Why are all processes killed when a terminal session ends?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, system-calls

Not long ago, I wondered about the question: why are all processes killed when you close a terminal on Linux, and not passed to the "init" process (with pid 1)?
Because, all child processes are adopted by "init" process after termination of the parent.
Please, help me understand difference and the errors in my reasoning.

And also:
If it's possible, then can we use a system call to stop this happening? I think, that for this the programs need use `setsid()`, but in practice it's not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why on close terminal on linux all his processes will terminated, but
>   not passed to "init" process (with pid 1)

The processes are losing their controlling terminal so the kernel sends them a `SIGHUP`. The  default action of `SIGHUP` is to terminate the process.

Comment: Can i do in my program analogue?
Which system call use for this?

Comment: But setsid() return -1.
I use setsid() and after i create few process with using fork().

Comment: @Simplex Time to dig out Stevens (Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment) or Rochkind, or a similar book.  The issue is covered in detail.  Part of the trick is for the child process to ignore SIGHUP, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But if the child dissociates itself from the session all will be fine, no ?

Comment: That's another way to do it, too.  Making sure you're fully disassociated from a terminal is the trick, though.  You can use `setpgid()` too (and `setpgrp()` if you don't mind variant definitions of what it does).

Comment: You can do your work in a screen and detach from it before exiting your terminal/logging off. Attach to the screen again from another session and it'll still be there and running.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
I investigate this question in details through Stevens book

Answer (score 2):

As explained by cnicutar, it's due to the `SIGHUP` sent to all processes in the process group associated with the controlling terminal. You may either install a handler for this signal or ignore it completely. For arbitrary programs, you can start them with the `nohup` utility designed for this purpose.

You can also place the process in a new process group without a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you to understand
http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/18802/10189/